# Free SQL Server in Azure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm creating a MVC 5 web application with EF 6 Code first. Now it creates a database in the App_Data folder. I want to publish the website to an Azure website. Because this is only the test version of the website, I don't want to pay for it. It will only visited a couple of times a month until it is in production.

Is it possible to run the database something like an access database file? I thought that some kind of functionality existed. I thought the name was SQL Server Compact Edition? But how does it works?

I also thought that you could create a free 20MB sql server database. See this link of the pricing page. Search for 20 in your browser. 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/
I don't see that option.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the 20Mb free SQL Server option. I still had a website in my subscription that was stopped. When I deleted that, no website or database was there in my subscription anymore. I then created a new website via the custom website option in the azure portal. I then could select (in the wizard) a free 20 MB SQL Server database.

I uploaded my MVC application and the Code First created my database automatically. I don't know why the option wasn't showing up before but now it works.

Comment: Looks like they've stopped this now.

Comment: Ignore that, it just doesn't work on the new portal, you have to use the old one.

Comment: It is sill possible using the new portal. Just go to "Resource Groups" > "Add Resource" > "Web App + SQL". Its a 32Mb Database now looks like.

Comment: @DaveWilliams Is "Web App + SQL" free?

Comment: @FelipeOriani If you use the method in my comment it is.

Comment: Note that as of Feb 2021 the mentioned 32MB Azure SQL database is limited to 5 DTU and free for 365 days after which plan switches from Free to Basic (around 5GBP per month), so technically it's a trial that is not suitable for production.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, you just have to **right click and include in your project**.

I write an [article](https://asing1001.github.io/2014/09/17/Azure-Websites-SQLDatabase-for-free/) for this in Chinese, and [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=883) is the English version I found.

### Solution for free SQL Server in Azure:

1. Install two nuget: `EntityFrame.SqlServerCompact` & `Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition`
2. Put SQL database file (.sdf/.mdf) in `APP_Data` folder
3. Put connection string like this to use it:

   ```
   <add name ="DefaultConnection" connectionString ="Data Source=|DataDirectory|CompactDB.sdf" providerName ="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
   ```
4. Publish full project include above SQL database file to AzureWebsites.
5. It work well and is totally free.

Comment: Heck yes! Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 2):

There's no free version of the SQL Database service.  What you may have read is that there's a 1 year free 20MB MySQL database available.

When you're saying that a database it created in the App_Data folder, this uses SQL Server Compact (see Maresh's links) and that is free.

Comment: Well there is a 20MB Sql Server AND MySQL version. See the link in the topic post. I quote: "Relational Database: one 20MB Azure SQL Database and one 20MB MySQL database are available at the subscription level for the first twelve months of use"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect on premise database you need to setup azure virtual network.  See the codeproject article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261063/Azure-Virtual-Network-Connecting-Local-Database

there is some alternative way using azure service bus.

http://www.bradygaster.com/post/windowsazurewebsites-onprem-servicebus

Another option would be sql server compact edition.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx

see below link also

[Support for SQL Server Compact 4.0 on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182933/support-for-sql-server-compact-4-0-on-azure)

Answer (score 0):

Since 2023, Azure offers a free plan for Azure SQL Database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/free-offer?view=azuresql

You will get every month:

- first 32 GB storage free
- first 100,000 vCore seconds free

One limitation is that the database automatically pauses after one hour of inactivity. When you want to resume, the initial request may take around 30 to 60 seconds.