# MVC App Doesn't correctly deploy in to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, publishing

I have a MVC 4 app built in c# using VS2013 Express Web.
All works fine locally. I have a SQL CE file on this app as well.

Every time I publish from Azure it publishes fine but when I go to the website it says
"We're sorry, we've hit an unexpected error. Click here if you'd like to go back and try that again."
Is there a way to deploy MVC apps with SQL CE attached to it.

Comment: This post may have some helpful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182933/support-for-sql-server-compact-4-0-on-azure

Comment: Any other Cloud services I can deploy this as it is ?