# Azure app services Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm trying to upload my web app written in ASP.NET WebAPI2 to Azure app services and when doing this I get a

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0
```

error.

I've tried out to:

- locally switch between SQLServerCE dependencies x86 and x64 (Private/Desktop references), and then upload again,
- upload the _bin_dependencies folder as the MVC 5 sample does,
- add the "x86" folder with the 32bit libraries inside myapp/bin...

with no success. Locally my app works like a charm. What can I do? I cannot install / configure IIS / edit Regedit in Azure since I'm using the "App Services" thing...

Answer (score 0):

We solved it awhile ago by following [this post](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/883/host-aspnet-mvc-azure-without-database) guidance . That [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182933/support-for-sql-server-compact-4-0-on-azure) is also helpful as it lists some of the limitations you may have with SQL Server CE.

Basically, as it does not come with NuGet, you need to set some things up to be sure that this library will come to Azure with your project.

Comment: I'm afraid that the first link doesn't work and the link included in the solution of the second link doesn't work either :/

Comment: I suppose the answer is no, but is it possible that I can use SQLServer in App Services?

Comment: Sorry, did not understand - does the link not work for you at all or something  else? It is working for me. Regarding SQL Server - only external service (you may create the SQL Server/Azure when creating the Web App)

Comment: In the end I resigned and moved to Amazon AWS, which is free for 1 year if you start small :)